# android drag and drop list items

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm beginner in Android development. I wanna drag and drop my list ( I'm using `ArrayAdapter`s. The values are stored in `Sqlite DataBase`). The examples, I saw, were for strings in a `ListView` thing. But I have list items.

Followed the https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList for drag and drop. But dunno exactly how to do for my list and handling the database (how to save after the drag and drop and also how to fetch the item name and id).

I tried it doing for my list but my project got crashed!!

Comment: I got the drag and drop perfectly working.. Can u give idea for how to store the value in the database so that i can retrieve back the list in the same order as sorted.

Comment: From your question i think all the data is with you. so I simply create a db and use

Comment: how can i save the new positions after the sort and use them for displaying?? (i wan the list to displayed in reverse order)

Answer (score 0):

to save the data into the database, you need use the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) to create the table, and use [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) to insert records into the tables.

after that, you can fetch the data using these two objects.